# Nexus - using Maven and uDeploy to fetch all modules in multi-module project

Tags: maven, nexus, udeploy

I have a multi-module Java Maven project. This project is stored in Nexus. I'm trying to use uDeploy to fetch all artifacts associated with parent POM and deploy to a target server.

UDeploy allows for the configuration of components which can have a 1:1 mapping with a Nexus artifact. Instead of creating individual components for each of my projects artifacts i would like to simply use the artifact ID of the projects parent POM and use this to pull in all dependencies.

In order to do this i need to know if its possible to fetch all of a multi-module projects modules from Nexus by simply having the parent pom?

Maybe someone has a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent pom of a project and many intermediary pom files in a multi-module project will use packaging pom. These provide no value for deployment to a production server.

For deployment with uDeploy you are probably only interested in certain project in the multi-module project. However there is no way for a client side tool to know automatically.

E.g. a WAR might be needed for deployment or it might just be bundles inside an EAR, which needs to be deployed. Therefore you need to specify the exact versions of the artifacts that should be pulled in by uDeploy.

And typically you dont have to worry about dependencies since they are bundled inside the WAR or EAR by the Maven build.

Comment: thanks Moser, on further investigation separating the wars and having a 1:1 mapping with uDeploy components provides a more flexible environment.